# .empty() is not working using js in PHP in my ajax poll

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to update my poll when people press on vote. everything is fine, except that I don't redirect to the result. to simplify the matter I am just trying to empty the div holding my poll after user press VOTE. Here is the code

```
$js = "
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
    $('poll_vote_".$poll->id."').addEvent('submit', function(e) {
      new Event(e).stop();

      $('submit_vote_".$poll->id."').disabled = 1;
          $('poll_loading_".$poll->id."').setStyle('display','');
      // Update the page
      this.send({ 
          onComplete: function(response, responseXML) {
                    $('polldiv_".$poll->id."').empty(); 
          }});

        }); 
 }); 
$document->addScriptDeclaration( $js );
```

Now everything is fine (and I get the votes correctly), but  $('polldiv_".$poll->id."').empty(); this is not working at all.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work as you intend, and what does the final generated HTML code look like?

Comment: Ugh, don't generate variables into your PHP like that. And that's not how jQuery selectors work. Go read the documentation again.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `polldiv_<poll-id>` and the other selectors correspond to tag ID's, you need to prefix the selectors with a `#` character.

---

Edit: So basically the final rendered HTML should be something like: `$('#polldiv_POLL-ID')`

Answer (score 0):

If you're selecting by ID, you're missing the `#` in every reference. `$('poll_vote_".$poll->id."')` should be `$('#poll_vote_".$poll->id."')`.